# Noob question: How to make a criteria on the count of an association?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm starting with NHibernate.

I have a type called `Person` which has a collection of `Address`.

How do I fetch:

> All people with at least 2 addresses

using ICriteria? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use subqueries.

```
Address alias = null;
ICriteria criteria = personsCriteria.CreateCriteria<Person>(x => x.Address, () => alias);
var addressCount = DetachedCriteria.For<Address>();
addressCount.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());
addressCount.Add<Address>(x => x.User.Id == alias.Id);
criteria.Add(Subqueries.Eq(2, addressCount));
```

I'm using ICriteria lambda extensions. You can look at them [here](http://code.google.com/p/nhlambdaextensions/)